# WSO2 Identity - XACML Simple Editor - Try It with Time Range - Error

Tags: wso2, editor, identity, xacml

Following the instructions for Simple Editor, I'm experiencing difficulties to use the environment time range parameter under WSO2 Version 5. The test displays an error:

```
<StatusMessage>Invalid request  : DOM of request element can not be created from String</StatusMessage>
```

The definition was added with the syntax: [06:00:00+05:00, 19:00:00+05:00]

Below you find the resulting XACML code generated by the Simple Editor:

**Policy**

```
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" PolicyId="TodaysPolicy" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable" Version="1.0">
   <Description>Doctor</Description>
   <Target>
      <AnyOf>
         <AllOf>
            <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-regexp-match">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">^(http:)</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
            </Match>
         </AllOf>
      </AnyOf>
   </Target>
   <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Rule-1">
      <Condition>
         <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">
               <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of">
                  <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
                     <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
                     <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">write</AttributeValue>
                     <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">delete</AttributeValue>
                  </Apply>
                  <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
               </Apply>
               <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">
                  <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:time-greater-than-or-equal">
                     <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:time-one-and-only">
                        <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:environment:current-time" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:environment" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#time" MustBePresent="true"/>
                     </Apply>
                     <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#time">06:00:00 05:00</AttributeValue>
                  </Apply>
                  <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:time-less-than-or-equal">
                     <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:time-one-and-only">
                        <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:environment:current-time" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:environment" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#time" MustBePresent="true"/>
                     </Apply>
                     <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#time">19:00:00 05:00</AttributeValue>
                  </Apply>
               </Apply>
            </Apply>
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of">
               <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">admin</AttributeValue>
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">doctor</AttributeValue>
               </Apply>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/claims/role" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
            </Apply>
         </Apply>
      </Condition>
   </Rule>
   <Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="Deny-Rule"/>
</Policy>
```

**Request** (with adjusted ID fields for claims/role and current-time):

```
<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="false">
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="false">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">write</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
<Attribute AttributeId="http://wso2.org/claims/role" IncludeInResult="false">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">doctor</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:environment">
<AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:environment:current-time" IncludeInResult="false">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">08:00:00+05:00</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="false">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">http://localhost:9444/medicalrecords</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
</Request>
```

Thanks in advance for your support. 
Regards, 
Claude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below a syntax that supports time window based authorization:

**Policy built by simple editor in XACML format**

resource input was:   {^(http:)}

role input was:       doctor | admin

action input was:     read | write | delete

time field input was: [06:00:00+05:00,20:00:00+05:00]

Result: Permit

```
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" PolicyId="TodaysPolicy" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable" Version="1.0">
   <Description>Rules with time</Description>
   <Target>
      <AnyOf>
         <AllOf>
            <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-regexp-match">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">^(http:)</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
            </Match>
         </AllOf>
      </AnyOf>
   </Target>
   <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Rule-1">
      <Condition>
         <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">
               <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of">
                  <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
                     <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
                     <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">write</AttributeValue>
                     <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">delete</AttributeValue>
                  </Apply>
                  <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
               </Apply>
               <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">
                  <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:time-greater-than-or-equal">
                     <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:time-one-and-only">
                        <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:environment:current-time" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:environment" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#time" MustBePresent="true"/>
                     </Apply>
                     <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#time">06:00:00 05:00</AttributeValue>
                  </Apply>
                  <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:time-less-than-or-equal">
                     <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:time-one-and-only">
                        <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:environment:current-time" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:environment" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#time" MustBePresent="true"/>
                     </Apply>
                     <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#time">20:00:00 05:00</AttributeValue>
                  </Apply>
               </Apply>
            </Apply>
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of">
               <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">doctor</AttributeValue>
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">admin</AttributeValue>
               </Apply>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/claims/role" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
            </Apply>
         </Apply>
      </Condition>
   </Rule>
   <Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="Deny-Rule"/>
</Policy>
```

**Request – Includes Current Time**

```
    <Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="false"> 
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action"> 
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="false"> 
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue> 
</Attribute> 
</Attributes> 
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject"> 
<Attribute AttributeId="http://wso2.org/claims/role" IncludeInResult="false"> 
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">admin</AttributeValue> 
</Attribute> 
</Attributes> 
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource"> 
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="false"> 
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">http://localhost:9444/medicalrecords</AttributeValue> 
</Attribute> 
</Attributes> 
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:environment">
<Attribute IncludeInResult="false" AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:environment:current-time" >
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#time">08:00:00+05:00</AttributeValue> 
</Attribute> 
</Attributes> 
</Request>
```

Hope this sample helps to clarify the structure of the request.

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that coding the current time directly into the request makes this work, it should not be necessary. The XACML 3.0 standard requires the PDP to supply the current time if it is not present in the request.